# Embedded Audio Element - HTTP 403 or CORS error in Chrome. How to fix?

Tags: http, cors, chromium, html5-audio

I have a web app running on localhost - accessing using Chromium browser.
I am embedding references to external sites - podcast episodes (mp3 files).
Some links work, others refuse to work - I receive a HTTP 403 or CORS error, depending on how I configure the  tag.

Example: first two are variations on the non-working mp3, the third shows a working mp3.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Podcast Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Test One : no cross-origin specified </h1>

<audio
    id="audioplayer1"
    src="http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/mediaselector/6/redir/version/2.0/mediaset/audio-nondrm-download/proto/http/vpid/p02pnpbm.mp3"
    controls crossorigin="anonymous">
</audio>

<h1> Test Two : cross-origin specified </h1>
<audio
    id="audioplayer2"
    src="http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/mediaselector/6/redir/version/2.0/mediaset/audio-nondrm-download/proto/http/vpid/p02pnpbm.mp3"
    controls/>
</audio>

<h1> Test Three : different feed (works) </h1>
<audio
    id="audioplayer3"
    src="http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/mediaselector/6/redir/version/2.0/mediaset/audio-nondrm-download/proto/http/vpid/p02t4hyw.mp3"
    controls/>
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Things to note:

- The response back from the server includes the following header, suggesting the website owner is NOT trying to prevent cross-site references:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

- I don't have this issue on Firefox
- The request goes through a HTTP 302->look-here-instead-dance (that is: using 'curl' I have to use the --location flag), but this is true of the working example above also.

Chromium:
Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Example MP3s taken from these BBC feeds [feed1](https://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/b01n7094.rss) and [feed2](https://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/b05qqhqp.rss) respectively.